# Помогите составить правильный sql Between запрос

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

У меня есть таблица с именем table в ней строки типа varchar в ней есть две колонки col1 и col2.
Колонки забиты значениями с плавающей точкой, пример: col1 = 2.234 col2 = 5.212; и т.д.

я составляю запрос на sql php (redbeanphp)
`$sql = R::find( 'table', 'col1 BETWEEN 1.75 AND 3.78 AND col2 BETWEEN 4.53 AND 5.55' );`

И кажется этот запрос должен вернуть col1 = 2.234 col2 = 5.212; но он ничего не возвращает.

Если я делаю запрос через phpmyadmin `` SELECT * FROM `shops` WHERE col1 BETWEEN 1.75 AND 3.78 AND col2 BETWEEN 4.53 AND 5.55 ``
то все работает.

Еще странно если в этом запросе `$sql = R::find( 'table', 'col1 BETWEEN 1.75 AND 3.78 AND col2 BETWEEN 4.53 AND 5.55' );` поменять числа на переменные в которых будут теже числа то запрос вернётся, то только в ответе будет пусто.

Comment: очевидно что-то неправильно в синтаксисе. А что выдаст var_dump($sql)? Посмотрите св-тва объекта, может там запрос не правильный?

Comment: ничего не возвращает ```var_dump($sql)``` при таком запросе ```$sql = R::find( 'table', 'col1 BETWEEN 1.75 AND 3.78 AND col2 BETWEEN 4.53 AND 5.55' );``` но если сделать так объявляем переменные ```$num1 =1.75 ;$num2=3.78;$num3=4.53;$num4=5.55; $sql = R::find( 'table', 'col1 BETWEEN' .$num1. 'AND' .$num2. 'AND col2 BETWEEN' .$num3. 'AND' .$num4 );``` то запрос вернёт ```array(0){} N```

Comment: Выполните явное приведение типов полей к числовому. Ну то есть тупо "плюс ноль".

Comment: сделал, тоже самое. уже не знаю что пробовать. мыслей нет у меня.